# Ajax e Asp.net MVC return "result is undefined"

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#btEmail").click(function () {
        var name = $("#username").val();

        $.post("@Url.Action("SearchUserByUsername", "LogonWorkFlow")", { username: name }, function (result) {
            var r = result;

        });
    });
});
```

Controller MVC:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SearchUserByUsername(string username)
        {
            return Json(GetUserByEmail(username), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

public async Task<JsonResult> GetUserByEmail(string email)
        {
            var u = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

            var user = new { mail = u.Email, n = u.FullName };

            return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

The request usually passes by function, but the return is always empty

Answer (score 2):

You're not retuning a string, you're returning a *task*.  Which the JSON serializer doesn't know what to do with and which has no meaningful string representation to return to the client.  `SearchUserByUsername` should also be `async`.  Something like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SearchUserByUsername(string username)
{
    return Json(await GetUserByEmail(username), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

That way it can *await* the call to `GetUserByEmail`, which is `async`.

---

Although since `GetUserByEmail` *already* returns a `JsonResult` you can (and probably should) simplify:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SearchUserByUsername(string username)
{
    return await GetUserByEmail(username);
}
```

Of course, at this point it begs the question of why you really need the `SearchUserByUsername` operation in the first place, since it's just a pass-through to an existing operation.